# .net How to update value of a field

Tags: c#, .net, update

```
  public void MssSetClientComments(RCSForce_SessionRecord ssSessionToken, string ssSearchesId, string ssComment, string ssContactId)
        {
            String queryString = "SELECT Comments__c FROM ts2__Application__c WHERE ts2__Job__c = '" + ssSearchesId + "' AND ts2__Client__c = '" + ssContactId + "'";
            SessionInfo sessionInfo = SessionInfoCache.Instance[ssSessionToken];
            QueryResult qr = sessionInfo.Binding.query(queryString);
            sObject []sforceObj = qr.records;
            SaveResult[] saveResults = sessionInfo.Binding.update(sforceObj);
  }
```

Where and how do i change the value now of the `Comments__c` that I pulled?

Comment: are you using the partner or enterprise WSDL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the Partner API, you update the XmlElement in the `sObject.Any` array that corresponds to the Comments__c field.

1. For each sObject in the sforceObj array...
2. Find the XmlElement in `sObject.Any` with the LocalName of "Comments__c"
3. Assuming you aren't trying to clear the field or set a blank value, Set the XmlElement.InnerText to the new value.

There are various extra checks you might need to do here. What if there isn't a XmlElement with a matching LocalName? What if you are trying to blank out the value? Does the new field value meet the maximum length requirements for the field...

You might find it easier to use a toolkit or library that hides these details from you. There are various ones available for .NET based projects. E.g.

- The [Salesforce Toolkits for .NET](http://www.wadewegner.com/2014/01/announcing-the-salesforce-toolkits-for-net/). Note that this uses the REST API rather than the SOAP based partner API.
- [G4S](http://www.fuseit.com/en/Solutions/G4S.aspx) (Paid + Full Disclosure - I work for the company that sells this). We've wrapped the Partner API calls to, among other things, give you strongly typed entity generation using T4 templates and support for .NET data types.

You can see C# examples of query and update, including the `.Any` XmlElements in:

- [Sample query and queryMore Calls](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sample_query_calls.htm)
- [Sample update Call](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sample_update_call.htm)

Comment: I cannot Find any good docs on `Any` I still have no clue how to update this one field.

Comment: The `Any` XmlElements are more a product of how C# processes the WSDL. I've updated the answer to show a couple of examples of the usage.